# Breaking up a large texture used by multiple meshes

Tags: texturing, uv

hoping someone can help us come up with a workflow for a problem we're trying to solve.
We've created a model with 3 materials with highly detailed, high resolution, textures. Each of these materials also contain a high resolution normal texture.
We have broken the model up into 100 unique standalone meshes which will be exported from Blender individually and head off on their own to different locations. Each of these individual models share the same UV mapping and three materials as the original uncut model but obviously contain only a portion of the original mesh.
Here lies our issue.
Because all of the 100 standalone models use the full high resolution texture maps (which we love, because they're beautiful) their export sizes are almost as large as the original.
Does anyone know a streamlined workflow we can use on the exported models to cut down the textures to what's being used by the model and resize the UV Map accordingly?
Everything I've looked into seems to involve a complex rebaking process, which repeated 100 times, could be the death of us.